# To find the maximum and minimum name of of the average salary that employee earn

Tags: python

I am new to the python. I ran into the problem. I have grouped a employee based on the location and i need to find the average of each empolyer pays. I need to find the name of the employer who have highers t and lowest salary. i have done this

```
Employer_group= universities.groupby('Location')
average_salary_university=Employer_group['Salary ($)'].agg(np.mean)
```

I couldn't find the name of lowest and highest average salary employer

Comment: Please provide some example data like the data you're using and add the imports you're using, to demonstrate the whole problem as a reproducible example.

Comment: I am sorry. You are grouping on location . How do you expect to get the name of the employer. You need to include name column along with location.

Comment: The information is insufficient. Please provide the table structure(s)